# Ajax result not passed to controller after mvc razor form is submitted

Tags: ajax, model-view-controller, razor

I have the following table on an MVC razor view.

```
<div id="tablecontainer">
    <table class="table" id="bookmarks">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="th-min-width">Select</th>
            <th class="th-min-width">Description</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        @for(var i=0; i < Model.Foos.Count(); i++)
        {
            <tr>
                <td class="td-min-width">
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(x=> x.Foos[i].Selected)
                </td>
                <td class="td-min-width">
                    @Model.Foos[i].Description
                </td>
            </tr>
         }
        </tbody>
    </table>
 </div>
```

I have written the following ajax function which repopulated the table.

```
    $('#DropdownId').change(function() {
        var param1= $(this).val();
        var param2= $("#bar").val();.ajax({
url: "@(Url.Action("method", "Controller"))",
type: "POST",
data: { "param1": param1, "param2": param2},
dataType: "json",
success: function (results) {
    var row = "";
    row += "<table class='table'>";
    row += "<thead><tr><th class='th-min-width'>Select</th> <th class='th-min-width'>BookmarkID</th>";
    row += "</tr></thead><tbody>";
    var index = 0;
    $.each(eval(results), function (key, result) {
        row += "<td><input type='checkbox' name='ForceBookmarks[" + index + "].Selected' value='" + result.Selected + "'></td>";
        row += "<td class='td-min-width'>" + result.Description + "</td>";
        index = index + 1;
    });
    row += "</tbody></table>";
    $('#tablecontainer').empty();
    $('#tablecontainer').html(row);
},
error: function(result) {
    alert("Error");
}
```

});

The table has a checkbox column for the user to select a row. After the ajax method has been called when the user checks a checkbox and submits the form the selected row is not sent to the controller

I’m not sure if I’m missing a binding or naming the checkbox incorrectly but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you update your question with complete jquery? i mean the part when the ajax gets called. you have directly started from .ajax

Comment: And I strongly feel you are missing the bindings. Since you are adding elements dynamically. I can help you out with a solution if you can provide additional details

Comment: I've added the requested code. I omitted it as I it is only passing parameters into the ajax function onchange of a dropdown. But if it helps then here it is :-)

Comment: is this `$("#bar").val()` your checkbox value??

Comment: No, its just a value on the form. The checkbox value is not passed into the ajax request. The checkboxes should all be unchecked after the ajax response. This all works successfully. The issue is after the ajax has been run if the user then checks a checkbox and submits a form the value is not sent to the controller and is not even in the request object

Comment: what value is not sent??

Comment: are you saying that the param1 and param2 is not sent to server the second time? Also I see you have used data1 and data2 in your code above and not defined it anywhere.

Comment: The names of the variables should of been data1 and data2 not param1 and param 2. I have amended the post. They may very well be sent when the form is finally submitted but they are not relevant to the problem. Once the ajax has been called and then later the form submitted teh value held in  @Html.CheckBoxFor(x=> x.Foos[i].Selected) is not sent to the server

Comment: Is your table inside your form? Also for a form submit the name attribute of the input element must match with either the input parameter of the controller action or if the input parameter is a Model (class) then the name attribute must match the object property name. Only then MVC will bind your data succesfully. Else you might have to end up writing a custom model binder, where you override default model binder and write your own logic to extract value from the request sent to server and map it to object properties

Comment: Let me know if my understanding of your problem is correct

Comment: I think you might be right. It could be down to the naming of the checkbox in the ajax response. Do you know what name razor would give @Html.CheckBoxFor(x=> x.Foos[i].Selected)?

Comment: hard to guess But definitely it wont be right, I guess it would be something like Object.Selected

Comment: and definitely `name='ForceBookmarks[" + index + "].Selected'` this code of yours will set the name to be `name='ForceBookmarks[0].Selected'`

Comment: When viewing the page source on first load (before ajax is triggered) the html is `<input class="ForceSelectedFlag" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Selected field is required." id="ForceBookmarks_0__Selected" name="ForceBookmarks[0].Selected" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="ForceBookmarks[0].Selected" type="hidden" value="false" />` so I would of thought this would of worked :-( Still stuck

Comment: Just set a proper name then. Let it be static like before